# How to switch activities without animation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I read a lot of similar questions but no one solution helped me. Now, I have the next code of `LauncherActivity`:

```
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DIAware {
    override val di by closestDI()
    private val getAccount: GetAccountUseCase by instance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()

        val activityClass = if (this.getAccount() == null) {
            LoginActivity::class.java
        } else {
            MainActivity::class.java
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, activityClass)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(0,0)
        finish()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

However, it works as long as I don't call `finish()`. If I call `finish()` animations begin to show again.

Where can the problem be? I have retried all possible combinations of these lines and flags, it doesn't work with `finish()`.

**P.S.** I know that I can use styles to turn off animations but it doesn't suit for my purposes, I need a solution to achieve it programmatically.

Comment: Why is `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` called at the end?

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Themes.xml

```
<style name="noAnimation" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity" 
   android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
    </activity>
```

Comment: i think this will work for you

Comment: I was needed to achieve it **programmatically**